# How to delete records in CRM 2011 by query?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to delete a set of entities in CRM 2011 by a attribute value. Ex. delete * from contacts where ContactId = "guid"...

How can I do this using the IOrganizationService?

Stig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two possibilities

- Retrieve all records with a QueryExpression which you would like to delete. Iterate over this collection and call [`IOrganizationService.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.delete.aspx) for all of them.
- You could run a [`BulkDeleteRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.bulkdeleterequest.aspx) which runs the deletion as a background task. See [how to run a bulk delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334582.aspx) or the [Sample: Bulk Delete Records That Match Common Criteria](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh670605.aspx)